# TableHeaderView and headers of sections

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header

I am able to add view to the tableHeaderView using the below mentioned code:-

```
MyView *view=[[MyView alloc] init];
.....
tableView.tableHeaderView=view;
```

But, I am unable to add spacing between this view and headers of first section.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I cannot understand your question, where do you want to put the spacE?

Comment: Spacing here refers to the GAP between **tableHeaderView** and **1st Section** (which also has a header)

Comment: Why dont you add this space to the header on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate your main view like this:

```
MyView *view=[[MyView alloc] init];
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height + 5)]; //5 pixel gap
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
[headerView addSubview:view];
.....
tableView.tableHeaderView=headerView;
```

I've created a new `headerView`, added the view to *that* view, and then set the `tableHeaderView` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that i can think is that you create a 'parent' view with height = (view.frame.height + )

Then add 'view' as a subview of 'parent' view and set 'parent' view as your table header.